# bpy.context... --> no attribute error

Tags: python, operator

I have a script that works fine from the text editor. It's a button nested in the sequencer header :

```
class mybutton(bpy.types.Operator):  
    bl_label = "mylabel"
    bl_idname = "sequencer.myidname"
    bl_description = ""

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if bpy.context.scene == bpy.data.scenes['myscene']
```

Now, when I turn the script into an addon, this line:

> if bpy.context.scene == bpy.data.scenes['myscene']:

throws this error:

> AttributeError:NoneType object has no attribute context

Any idea why ? How can I get the active scene otherwise ?

Thanks a ton !

Comment: Likely you somehow managed to assign `None` to bpy. would need entire script to see why, but I suspect this is caused by some strange API use.

Comment: also, you should use the context given in the call to `invoke` not `bpy.context`. You "can" use `bpy` everywhere else though.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers ! I got it working after hours of trial and errors... it seems that my entire code is made of "strange API use"...

Comment: @Nikos_VSE would also write what you found for this as answer